# Problems authenticating with Active Directory || "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad credentials"

Tags: active-directory, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I have this code in my spring security configuration file `@Bean @Lazy public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() { log.info("*************DOMINIOLDAP**********" + domainldap); log.info("***********URL LDAP****************"+ urlLdap); ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(domainldap, urlLdap); adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true); adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true); log.info("***********PROVIDER***************"+ adProvider); return adProvider; }` and it lets me authenticate with my AD credentials when it is in my local environment and when it is deployed in kubernetes in the QA environment, but when it is deployed in production I get the following error `{ "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad credentials" }`

I set up my service in my local environment pointing to the production variables and it generates the access token, but deployed in the containers it does not generate it and it gives me a credentials error, I still cannot find the error, check the environment variables of the containers and they are well configured as in QA, I need help, I am blocked